# Retrieve public SSH key from private key file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, aws-lambda, cryptography

I have a private key file `id_rsa` (starts with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----). With the tool `ssh-keygen` I am able to generate an SSH public key using the following command:
`ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

The generated file will have the following content:

> ssh-rsa
> AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAklOUpkDHrfHY17SbrmTIpNLTGK9Tjom/BWDSU
> GPl+nafzlHDTYW7hdI4yZ5ew18JH4JW9j...

I am trying to achieve the same within my Python code. The code will be executed on AWS Lambda so I want to avoid invoking `os.system()` to run shell commands since I don't have control over the underlying environment.

Given that I have a variable `private_key`, how can I extract the ssh public key from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH now has its own format for private keys (*BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY*). Previously, the PKCS#1 or PKCS#8 format was used for private RSA keys. The posted private key has the PKCS#1 format (PEM encoded).

The [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) library supports a wide range of key formats, including PKCS#1 and the OpenSSH format. The following code allows importing a PKCS#1 formatted private key and exporting the public key in OpenSSH format:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

privatePkcs1Pem = b'''-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQE....QkFn5HuC2aOZjktdA==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'''

private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(privatePkcs1Pem, password=None)
public_key = private_key.public_key()
public_openssh = public_key.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.OpenSSH, format=serialization.PublicFormat.OpenSSH )

print(public_openssh.decode('utf-8')) # ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1...
```