# Retrieve public SSH key from private key file using Go

Tags: go, ssh, cryptography

I have a private key file `id_rsa` (starts with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----). With the tool `ssh-keygen` I am able to generate an SSH public key using the following command:
`ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

The generated file will have the following content:

> ssh-rsa
> AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAklOUpkDHrfHY17SbrmTIpNLTGK9Tjom/BWDSU
> GPl+nafzlHDTYW7hdI4yZ5ew18JH4JW9j...

I am trying to achieve the same within my Go code. The code will be executed on AWS Lambda so I want to avoid executing system commands with `os.exec` since I don't have control over the underlying environment.

Given that I have a variable `private_key`, how can I extract the ssh public key from it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve public SSH key from private key file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363862/retrieve-public-ssh-key-from-private-key-file-using-python)

Comment: You can proceed analogously to the Python case: Import the private key (using the pem, rsa and x509 packages), extract the public key and export it in OpenSSH format (both using the ssh package).

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for the guidance. However I coudln't figure how to export to OpenSSH format using only the packages from the standard library that you mentioned. See my answer below.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you mean. You used the packages mentioned in my comment in your posted answer. If you are referring to the (additional) Base64 encoding: This can be omitted with the following optimization `sshPubKey := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(pub)` and `return string(sshPubKey), nil`, s. also https://go.dev/play/p/OTCM_hzvWsQ. But this is just a little something.

Comment: @Topaco I just wanted to know if you there was a way of achieving the result using only the tools provided by the standard library (i.e without using the package `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh`). But I see that you also used it in your provided example. Thanks for the suggested optimization I will add it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to extract the public key in OpenSSH format, using packages *rsa*, *pem* and *x509* from the standard library and *golang.org/x/crypto/ssh*

```
import (
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func ParseRsaPrivateKeyFromPemStr(privPEM string) (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(privPEM))
    if block == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("failed to parse PEM block containing the key")
    }

    priv, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return priv, nil
}

func PublicPEMtoOpenSSH(rsaPubKey *rsa.PublicKey) (string, error) {

    pub, err := ssh.NewPublicKey(rsaPubKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    sshPubKey := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(pub)

    return string(sshPubKey), nil
}

func main() {

    private_PEM, err := os.ReadFile("path/to/file.pem")
    check(err)

    priv_parsed, err := ParseRsaPrivateKeyFromPemStr(string(private_PEM))
    check(err)

    openssh_key, err := PublicPEMtoOpenSSH(&priv_parsed.PublicKey)
    check(err)

    print(openssh_key) // ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA...

}
```